# Nested LESS to css classes

Tags: css, less, mixins, nested

I am trying to make some LESS from my css, for now i have made a lot, but i have problem with long selector of KENDO Grid, it wrappes element in strange places and then it is hard to find. This is what i have for now on

**LESS**

```
        .k-grid {
        .k-pager-wrap {
            .color-background(@white);
            border-top: 0 none;
        }

        .k-grid-header {
            .color-background(@white);

            thead tr[role="row"]:first-child {
                display: none;
            }

            .k-grid-header-wrap {
                table {
                    thead {
                        tr {
                            th.k-header {
                                font-size: @font-size-large;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .k-grid-content {
            overflow: auto !important;
        }
    }

     .k-pager-numbers {
    li {
        a.k-link {
            .color-text(@grey) !important;

            &:hover, &:active, &:focus, &:visited {
                .color-background(@grey-background) !important;
                .color-text(@brand) !important;
            }
        }

        .k-state-selected {
            .color-background(@grey-background) !important;
            border: medium none;
            .color-text(@brand);
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that i have is with another CSS that i am trying to put inisde of this k-grid, here is

**CSS**

```
        .k-grid-header-wrap table thead tr.k-filter-row th span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden button.k-button.k-button-icon {
    height: 26px;
}

.k-grid-header-wrap table thead tr.k-filter-row th span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden button.k-button.k-button-icon span.k-icon.k-i-close {
    margin-bottom:18px;
}


table thead tr.k-filter-row th span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden span.k-widget.k-autocomplete.k-header.k-state-focused,
table thead tr.k-filter-row th span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden span.k-widget.k-autocomplete.k-header.k-state-hover {
    .lh-box-shadow(none) !important;
    border-color: @grey-border !important;
}

.k-grid-header-wrap table thead tr.k-filter-row th {
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}


div.k-grid-header div.k-grid-header-wrap {
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 101%;
}
```

As you may see it is veery long selector, but all my CSS i need to convert to less I already have, just to append the LESS, can somebody help me. I have lost entire day for making this previous LESS now with this CSS i have no luck. Txanks

Comment: You have try online coverter css to less like [this](http://css2less.cc/)?

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya - you might want to post that as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you can give variables for your selectors. 
Your code can be like this:

```
  @first-long-selector: ~"span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden button.k-button.k-button-icon";
  @second-long-selector: ~"span.k-filtercell span.k-operator-hidden span.k-widget.k-autocomplete.k-header";
  @short-selector: k-grid-header;
  @table-selector: ~"table thead tr.k-filter-row th";

  .@{short-selector}{
    &-wrap{
      @{table-selector}{
          @{first-long-selector} {
          height: 26px;

            .k-icon.k-i-close{
              margin-bottom:18px;
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }

  @{table-selector}{
    @{second-long-selector}{
        &.k-state-focused,
        &.k-state-hover{
          .lh-box-shadow(none) !important;
          border-color: @grey-border !important;
        }  
    }
  }

  .@{short-selector}{
    &-wrap{
      @{table-selector}{
        padding-top:5px;
        padding-bottom:5px;
      }
    }
  }


  .@{short-selector}{
    & &-wrap{
      border-right-width: 0;
      width: 101%;
    }
  }
```

Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/ostinred/pen/eNQXYj?editors=110)

Comment: also you can do variables in variables, when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

LESS recognizes CSS. So you don't necessarily have to convert your CSS to LESS. Just copy it in as is if you just want to get it working.

Comment: I know but it has so long selector somebody must look that

Comment: Actually IMO the right indentation actually would make it a bit more difficult to maintain esp. since you're not adding additional styles at that level. But do take a look at Nikunj's suggestion - it seems like an awesome way to convert CSS to LESS. Cheers!